# MVC5 Portable Area, how do you use message bus?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, message-bus

I spent several hours reading through many different examples and documentation for setting up a portable area with ASP.NET MVC, with the intent of sharing a common login page with authentication for multiple applications. I got it all together and it works nicely so far, but one thing I'm having trouble with is the use of message bus. I see it is a way of communicating between the Host and Portable components, but I don't see a clear way of how to do this.

For instance; if my Portable login is successful, how do I tell the Host so it can do something (set a cookie, redirect to a specific page, etc.)? Also, if I want to send something to the Portable (like the title or Assembly Version of the Host application) how would I do that? I haven't tried anything yet because I cannot seem to find a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it all figured out. There was a [MvcContrib source code archive](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mvccontrib) that I was unable to download since Google Chrome was blocking the .zip file, but I was able to get it using Internet Explorer.

Here are the important bits after adapting it to my application. Hopefully this can help someone. I did my best to format my answer properly, this is my first time posting on StackOverflow:

**In the Portable class library**

1. Create a LoginResult class using the ICommandResult interface

   ```
   public class LoginResult: MvcContrib.PortableAreas.ICommandResult
   {
       public bool Success { get; set; }
       public string Message { get; set; }
       public string Username { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Create a LoginMessage class that also uses the ICommandResult interface with LoginResult. The LoginMessage class has a property for a LoginViewModel I use in my Login.cshtml view (it has Username, Password, and some other additional fields I needed for the view)

   ```
   public class LoginMessage : ICommandMessage<LoginResult>
   {
       public LoginResult Result { get; set; }
       public LoginViewModel Input { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. In the HttpPost action of the Login controller, create an instance of LoginMessage, passing in the LoginViewModel from the login view, and send it to the Host with MvcContrib.Bus.Send

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel mdl)
   {
       // TODO: Do basic auth here first, then send to Host for additional validation

       // Create and send message to the Host
       var message = new LoginMessage { Input = mdl, Result = new LoginResult() };

       MvcContrib.Bus.Send(message);

       if (message.Result.Success)
       {
           // Redirect to defaultUrl set in the Host's web.config
           FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(mdl.Username, false);
       }

       return View("Login", "_Layout", mdl);
   }
   ```

Note: LoginMessage sets a new empty LoginResult and then waits for Success. The Success is set by the Host (shown below). I do this because certain Host applications have specific additional logic that only apply to that application, so I let the Host do what it needs and return to the Portable to let it know if it passed or failed. Eventually, I will have the basic authentication logic in the Portable first and then let the Host do the extra work, but for the sake of this example I am keeping it simple.

**In the Host web application (which has a reference to my Portable dll)**

1. Create a handler for the Portable.LoginMessage so we can read it in the Host. Note that IsValidLogin is where I will eventually do my additional authentication logic to see if the user is valid

   ```
   public class LoginHandler : MvcContrib.PortableAreas.MessageHandler<Portable.LoginMessage>
   {
       public override void Handle(Portable.LoginMessage message)
       {
           if (IsValidLogin(message.Input.Username, message.Input.Password))
           {
               message.Result.Success = true;
               message.Result.Username = message.Input.Username;
           }
           else
           {
               message.Result.Message = "Username or Password was incorrect";
           }
       }

       private bool IsValidLogin(string username, string password)
       {
           // TODO: Replace with actual authentication
           return username.Equals("admin") && password.Equals("password");
       }
   }
   ```
2. In the web.config, set the defaultUrl that the Portable will redirect to in the controller I described earlier, when *message.Result.Success* is True. You do not need to be using Forms Authentication, the mode can be set to None, but you need to have the defaultUrl for this to work.

   ```
   <system.web>
       <authentication mode="Forms">
           <forms loginUrl="~/Portable/Login" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" />
       </authentication>
   </system.web>
   ```

That's it! This was a great exercise and learning experience for me. I am still figuring out the second part of my question where I need to send information to the Portable first (like the application title and assembly version) but I'm thinking I can do pretty much the same thing but in reverse, where I send an ICommandMessage to the Portable when my Host starts up (global.asax).